# Scikit-image: why major axis length is zero with multiple objects?

Tags: python, for-loop, image-processing, scikit-image

An image with multiple objects is labelled like this:

```
image=
[[ 1  0  0  0  2  2  0  3  3  3  3]
 [ 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  4  4]
 [ 4  0  5  5  0  0  0  0  6  6  6]
 [ 6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  7]
 [ 7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  8]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  9  9  9]
 [ 9  0  0  0  0  0 10 10 10 10 10]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12]
 [12 12  0  0 13 13  0  0  0  0 14]
 [14 14  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 15]]
```

Since I want to know about the major axis length of the equivalent ellipse, I use this function of image processing:

```
import skimage as sk
from skimage import measure
props=sk.measure.regionprops(image)
maj_ax_le=round(props[0].major_axis_length,3)
```

But when I ask for the result, I get:

```
In [1]: maj_ax_le
Out[1]: 0.0
```

Is this because of the presence of multiple objects (15, in this case)? If so, how can I compute the individual `maj_ax_le` for all the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can read in the [`regionprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=label#skimage.measure.regionprops) documentation:

> **Returns:**     **properties** : list of RegionProperties
>                               Each item describes one labeled region, and can be accessed using the
>                               attributes listed below.

Therefore, to get the major axis length of all the objects in your image, you simply need to iterate over `props`:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import regionprops

img = np.array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  2,  2,  0,  3,  3,  3,  3],
                [ 3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  4,  4],
                [ 4,  0,  5,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  6,  6],
                [ 6,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  7],
                [ 7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  8],
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9,  9,  9,  9],
                [ 9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11],
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 12],
                [12, 12,  0,  0, 13, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14],
                [14, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 15]])

props = regionprops(img)

print 'Label \tMajor axis'
for p in props:
    print '%5d %12.3f' % (p.label, p.major_axis_length)
```

And this is what you get:

```
Label   Major axis
    1        0.000
    2        2.000
    3       14.259
    4       15.934
    5        2.000
    6       15.934
    7       18.085
    8        2.000
    9       14.259
   10        5.657
   11        0.000
   12       18.085
   13        2.000
   14       18.085
   15        0.000
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! What do you think is the reason why the value associated with `maj_ax_le` was zero?

Comment: There are three labels, namely `1`, `11`, and `15` that occur only once in your image. As shown in the output produced by my script, the corresponding major axis lengths are `0.000`. Hence, the axis length of a single pixel object is zero.

Comment: ok, but why did the function return 0 `overall` if there are other objects with axis>0?

Comment: `props[0].major.axis.length` is the length of the major axis of the region labelled `1`, not the overall value. If you type in `props[1].major.axis.length` you should get the value `2.000`, `14.259` for `props[2].major.axis.length`, and so on.